# Datetime need the date only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column in SQL Server that is datetime this is a typical value

```
                 10/6/2016   8:40:00PM
```

I want to process just according to the date.

I want to group a report by date only. What must I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL Server 2008 and higher:

SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())